# rror: endorsement failure during invoke. response: status:500 message:"error in simulation: failed to execute transaction

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

peer chaincode invoke -o localhost:7050 --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com --tls --cafile "${PWD}/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem" -C mychannel -n basic --peerAddresses localhost:9051 --tlsRootCertFiles "${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt" --peerAddresses localhost:7051 --tlsRootCertFiles "${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt" -c '{"function":"CreateAsset","Args":["100","White","28","Harsh","12"]}'

Error: endorsement failure during invoke. response: status:500 message:"error in simulation: failed to execute transaction 88f6547b138e71db727c2540be448c43fe104e43ae1a8f756992cfb2050c758e: could not launch chaincode basic_1.0:47211f6621707350a526342d9fb2f63e00d62da5a1ea003936275c4f93193bf8: error starting container: error starting container: API error (400): OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "chaincode": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown"

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the chaincode is not (suitably) installed in the peer being invoked, or something similar.

Check installed and instantiated chaincodes with (I omit extra arguments related to your network):

```sh
peer chaincode list --installed
peer chaincode list --instantiated -C mychannel
```

It can also be related to some misconfiguration in your peers about chaincode.

Please check also your `main` function in your chaincode's `main` package.